# jQuery DataTables - Accent-Insensitive Alphabetization and Searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, non-ascii-characters, accent-insensitive

When using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) is it possible to do accent-insensitive searches when using the filter? For instance, when I put the 'e' character, I'd like to search every word with 'e' or 'é', 'è'.

Something that came to mind is normalizing the strings and putting them into a separate, hidden column but that wouldn't solve the alphabetizing issue.

### EDIT

I tried the following:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch = function ( data ) {
return ! data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
        data
            .replace( /\n/g, ' ' )
            .replace( /á/g, 'a' )
            .replace( /é/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /í/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /ó/g, 'o' )
            .replace( /ú/g, 'u' )
            .replace( /ê/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /î/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /ô/g, 'o' )
            .replace( /è/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /ï/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /ü/g, 'u' )
            .replace( /ç/g, 'c' ) :
        data;
};
```

[JS File Gist](https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/17f8ead5bec5273c07fe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are **so** close in your edit, what you have tried, except that you lack the must important thing : *Defining the "scope" or sType of your filter plugin*. The function is never called, right? This is because the plugin is not associated with a `sType`.

To get your code to work simply declare the plugin like this :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['string'] = function ( data ) {
return ! data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
..
..
}
```

See this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ycM/** I have turned some "Internet Explorer" columns into "Internet éxplorer", some "Opera" to "öpera" etc, Try search for `ex` or `op`.

---

See https://datatables.net/development/filtering, section "Type based column filtering
" :

> When you assign the sType for a column (or have it automatically
>   detected for you by DataTables or a type detection plug-in), you will
>   typically be using this for custom sorting, but it can also be used to
>   provide custom filtering options. *This is done by adding functions to
>   the the object with a **parameter name** which matches the sType for that
>   target column*:

I guess there here is a typo or oversight in the documentation, it says

`$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch` but should correctly be `$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch[sType]`, as the example just after clearly points out.

---

**Update**. Allan Jardine confirms this is a bug in 1.9.4 [**here**](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20105/-fn-datatableext-ofnsearchstype-does-not-work-in-1-9-4#Item_1) :

> Yup - bug in 1.9.4. 1.9.4 broke this part of the code unfortunately.
>   It also effects the removal of HTML tags from the filter, since that
>   was using the same mechanism. It is fixed in the 1.10 betas though.

Comment: *Sigh* still not getting it. Here's a gist to my actual js file. I must be missing something but the function still doesn't seem to be called. https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/17f8ead5bec5273c07fe

Comment: @hanleyhansen - Well, now I am the one not getting it :) Just copied your code into the fiddle above, after deleting all previous javascript (the only thing being reused is the table markup itself) - http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ycM/3/, it works fine. Tested in chrome, FF and Opera. Cannot switch to a windows box right now. The only thing I have commented out is your use of the chosen plugin at the very end, because it is not included in this fiddle.

Comment: I wonder, do you use a **really** old version of dataTables? The one used in the fiddle is v1.9.0

Comment: That is really weird. I'm using v1.9.4.

Comment: As an aside, I'm letting DataTables assign the sType for the columns just as an FYI.

Comment: @hanleyhansen, you are **absolutely** right!!?? See http://jsfiddle.net/ua6Rt/. The expected behaviour is completely broken in 1.9.4. Even if you force sType to be string. Even more strange, look at `core.filter.js`, `_fnDataToSearch` - it explicitly goes `if ( typeof DataTable.ext.ofnSearch[sType] === "function" )..` but is never called! I am suspecting that you have found a real bug in 1.9.4. Nothing should have been changed what so ever regarding the basic filter operations in 1.9.4. I will try to find out what is going on, why `ofnSearch` never is called. A bug or a undocumented change.

Comment: Interesting! Good stuff. I will award you the bounty and mark this as the answer. If you do find something. Please share.

Comment: I dont think you should do that, since my answer not solve your question.

Comment: To begin with, my goal was not to gain the 100pt, but to correct something i meant was wrong. Now I have realized, I dont have a clue of what really went wrong. I will investigate, but I dont deserve 100pt as bonus. See this in the meantime http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuTQq0dXm-M

Comment: Your contribution propelled me the closest to an answer or at least an understanding of the issue that's worth the 100 rep points i was willing to offer.

Comment: @hanleyhansen, see update - you actually found a bug in 1.9.4!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the update. I'll see about implementing it once there's a stable release. Thanks!

Comment: The fiddle does not work, when I enter "fírefox" nothing is found

Answer (score 8):

jQuery                           v:  2.1.0
jquery.dataTables.min.js         v:  1.10.7
dataTables.responsive.min.js     v:  1.0.6

I used the accent neutralise plugin from here (thanks Allan Jardine):
http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise

And just made minimal adaptations for my purposes:

I made an example combining the answers in: http://jsfiddle.net/xebtyaeL/5/

```
jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function ( data ) {
    return ! data ?
        '' :
        typeof data === 'string' ?
            data
                .replace( /έ/g, 'ε')
                .replace( /ύ/g, 'υ')
                .replace( /ό/g, 'ο')
                .replace( /ώ/g, 'ω')
                .replace( /ά/g, 'α')
                .replace( /ί/g, 'ι')
                .replace( /ή/g, 'η')
                .replace( /\n/g, ' ' )
                .replace( /[áÁ]/g, 'a' )
                .replace( /[éÉ]/g, 'e' )
                .replace( /[íÍ]/g, 'i' )
                .replace( /[óÓ]/g, 'o' )
                .replace( /[úÚ]/g, 'u' )
                .replace( /ê/g, 'e' )
                .replace( /î/g, 'i' )
                .replace( /ô/g, 'o' )
                .replace( /è/g, 'e' )
                .replace( /ï/g, 'i' )
                .replace( /ü/g, 'u' )
                .replace( /ã/g, 'a' )
                .replace( /õ/g, 'o' )
                .replace( /ç/g, 'c' )
                .replace( /ì/g, 'i' ) :
            data;
};

var tabla = jQuery('#datatable-table').dataTable( { } );
          new jQuery.fn.dataTable.Responsive( tabla );

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var table = jQuery('#datatable-table').DataTable();

      // Remove accented character from search input as well
      jQuery('#datatable-table_filter input').keyup( function () {
        table
          .search(
            jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string( this.value )
          )
          .draw();
      } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

In this [topic](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18763/key-problems-with-accent-spanish/p1) explain this issuse, the trick is to replace *strange characters* with a *normal character* (no accent character). So to speak way.

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function ( data ) {
    return ! data ?
        '' :
        typeof data === 'string' ?
            data
                .replace( /\n/g, " " )
                .replace( /[éêè]/g, 'e' ) :   //<------- remplace éêè by e
            data;
}
```

There is another [example](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise.js)

```
jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function ( data ) {
    return ! data ?
        '' :
        typeof data === 'string' ?
            data
                .replace( /\n/g, ' ' )
                .replace( /á/g, 'a' )
                .replace( /é/g, 'e' )
                .replace( /í/g, 'i' )
                .replace( /ó/g, 'o' )
                .replace( /ú/g, 'u' )
                .replace( /ê/g, 'e' )
                .replace( /î/g, 'i' )
                .replace( /ô/g, 'o' )
                .replace( /è/g, 'e' )
                .replace( /ï/g, 'i' )
                .replace( /ü/g, 'u' )
                .replace( /ç/g, 'c' ) :
            data;
};
```

Comment: What about alphabetization? Right now `é` is being placed after z.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try that tonight. Will this change `é` to `e` in the display?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I've updated my answer with the function i tried. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think Jean-Sébastien's solution (sorry, I can't just comment yet) is the only one that actually answers the question. If you type "Explorer" or "éxplorer, it should return "Explorer" AND "éxplorer". In previous suggestions, if one typed "éxplorer", the search would return nothing.

The trick is that his solution misses a part in the keyup function.

```
$('#example_filter input[type=search]').keyup(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.search(
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string(accents_supr(this.value))
    ).draw();
});
```

See this fiddle fork for a working demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/syvo/caxj9koL/

Comment: Just don't forget to lower case the string in your function to handle cases

Answer (score 1):

```
// (Long) list of all accented characters and their folded equivalents
var accent_map = {
'\n':' ','ẚ':'a','Á':'a','á':'a','À':'a','à':'a','Ă':'a','ă':'a','Ắ':'a','ắ':'a','Ằ':'a','ằ':'a','Ẵ':'a','ẵ':'a','Ẳ':'a','ẳ':'a','Â':'a','â':'a','Ấ':'a','ấ':'a','Ầ':'a','ầ':'a','Ẫ':'a','ẫ':'a','Ẩ':'a','ẩ':'a','Ǎ':'a','ǎ':'a','Å':'a','å':'a','Ǻ':'a','ǻ':'a','Ä':'a','ä':'a','Ǟ':'a','ǟ':'a','Ã':'a','ã':'a','Ȧ':'a','ȧ':'a','Ǡ':'a','ǡ':'a','Ą':'a','ą':'a','Ā':'a','ā':'a','Ả':'a','ả':'a','Ȁ':'a','ȁ':'a','Ȃ':'a','ȃ':'a','Ạ':'a','ạ':'a','Ặ':'a','ặ':'a','Ậ':'a','ậ':'a','Ḁ':'a','ḁ':'a','Ⱥ':'a','ⱥ':'a','Ǽ':'a','ǽ':'a','Ǣ':'a','ǣ':'a','Ḃ':'b','ḃ':'b','Ḅ':'b','ḅ':'b','Ḇ':'b','ḇ':'b','Ƀ':'b','ƀ':'b','ᵬ':'b','Ɓ':'b','ɓ':'b','Ƃ':'b','ƃ':'b','Ć':'c','ć':'c','Ĉ':'c','ĉ':'c','Č':'c','č':'c','Ċ':'c','ċ':'c','Ç':'c','ç':'c','Ḉ':'c','ḉ':'c','Ȼ':'c','ȼ':'c','Ƈ':'c','ƈ':'c','ɕ':'c','Ď':'d','ď':'d','Ḋ':'d','ḋ':'d','Ḑ':'d','ḑ':'d','Ḍ':'d','ḍ':'d','Ḓ':'d','ḓ':'d','Ḏ':'d','ḏ':'d','Đ':'d','đ':'d','ᵭ':'d','Ɖ':'d','ɖ':'d','Ɗ':'d','ɗ':'d','Ƌ':'d','ƌ':'d','ȡ':'d','ð':'d','É':'e','Ə':'e','Ǝ':'e','ǝ':'e','é':'e','È':'e','è':'e','Ĕ':'e','ĕ':'e','Ê':'e','ê':'e','Ế':'e','ế':'e','Ề':'e','ề':'e','Ễ':'e','ễ':'e','Ể':'e','ể':'e','Ě':'e','ě':'e','Ë':'e','ë':'e','Ẽ':'e','ẽ':'e','Ė':'e','ė':'e','Ȩ':'e','ȩ':'e','Ḝ':'e','ḝ':'e','Ę':'e','ę':'e','Ē':'e','ē':'e','Ḗ':'e','ḗ':'e','Ḕ':'e','ḕ':'e','Ẻ':'e','ẻ':'e','Ȅ':'e','ȅ':'e','Ȇ':'e','ȇ':'e','Ẹ':'e','ẹ':'e','Ệ':'e','ệ':'e','Ḙ':'e','ḙ':'e','Ḛ':'e','ḛ':'e','Ɇ':'e','ɇ':'e','ɚ':'e','ɝ':'e','Ḟ':'f','ḟ':'f','ᵮ':'f','Ƒ':'f','ƒ':'f','Ǵ':'g','ǵ':'g','Ğ':'g','ğ':'g','Ĝ':'g','ĝ':'g','Ǧ':'g','ǧ':'g','Ġ':'g','ġ':'g','Ģ':'g','ģ':'g','Ḡ':'g','ḡ':'g','Ǥ':'g','ǥ':'g','Ɠ':'g','ɠ':'g','Ĥ':'h','ĥ':'h','Ȟ':'h','ȟ':'h','Ḧ':'h','ḧ':'h','Ḣ':'h','ḣ':'h','Ḩ':'h','ḩ':'h','Ḥ':'h','ḥ':'h','Ḫ':'h','ḫ':'h','H':'h','̱':'h','ẖ':'h','Ħ':'h','ħ':'h','Ⱨ':'h','ⱨ':'h','Í':'i','í':'i','Ì':'i','ì':'i','Ĭ':'i','ĭ':'i','Î':'i','î':'i','Ǐ':'i','ǐ':'i','Ï':'i','ï':'i','Ḯ':'i','ḯ':'i','Ĩ':'i','ĩ':'i','İ':'i','i':'i','Į':'i','į':'i','Ī':'i','ī':'i','Ỉ':'i','ỉ':'i','Ȉ':'i','ȉ':'i','Ȋ':'i','ȋ':'i','Ị':'i','ị':'i','Ḭ':'i','ḭ':'i','I':'i','ı':'i','Ɨ':'i','ɨ':'i','Ĵ':'j','ĵ':'j','J':'j','̌':'j','ǰ':'j','ȷ':'j','Ɉ':'j','ɉ':'j','ʝ':'j','ɟ':'j','ʄ':'j','Ḱ':'k','ḱ':'k','Ǩ':'k','ǩ':'k','Ķ':'k','ķ':'k','Ḳ':'k','ḳ':'k','Ḵ':'k','ḵ':'k','Ƙ':'k','ƙ':'k','Ⱪ':'k','ⱪ':'k','Ĺ':'a','ĺ':'l','Ľ':'l','ľ':'l','Ļ':'l','ļ':'l','Ḷ':'l','ḷ':'l','Ḹ':'l','ḹ':'l','Ḽ':'l','ḽ':'l','Ḻ':'l','ḻ':'l','Ł':'l','ł':'l','Ł':'l','̣':'l','ł':'l','̣':'l','Ŀ':'l','ŀ':'l','Ƚ':'l','ƚ':'l','Ⱡ':'l','ⱡ':'l','Ɫ':'l','ɫ':'l','ɬ':'l','ɭ':'l','ȴ':'l','Ḿ':'m','ḿ':'m','Ṁ':'m','ṁ':'m','Ṃ':'m','ṃ':'m','ɱ':'m','Ń':'n','ń':'n','Ǹ':'n','ǹ':'n','Ň':'n','ň':'n','Ñ':'n','ñ':'n','Ṅ':'n','ṅ':'n','Ņ':'n','ņ':'n','Ṇ':'n','ṇ':'n','Ṋ':'n','ṋ':'n','Ṉ':'n','ṉ':'n','Ɲ':'n','ɲ':'n','Ƞ':'n','ƞ':'n','ɳ':'n','ȵ':'n','N':'n','̈':'n','n':'n','̈':'n','Ó':'o','ó':'o','Ò':'o','ò':'o','Ŏ':'o','ŏ':'o','Ô':'o','ô':'o','Ố':'o','ố':'o','Ồ':'o','ồ':'o','Ỗ':'o','ỗ':'o','Ổ':'o','ổ':'o','Ǒ':'o','ǒ':'o','Ö':'o','ö':'o','Ȫ':'o','ȫ':'o','Ő':'o','ő':'o','Õ':'o','õ':'o','Ṍ':'o','ṍ':'o','Ṏ':'o','ṏ':'o','Ȭ':'o','ȭ':'o','Ȯ':'o','ȯ':'o','Ȱ':'o','ȱ':'o','Ø':'o','ø':'o','Ǿ':'o','ǿ':'o','Ǫ':'o','ǫ':'o','Ǭ':'o','ǭ':'o','Ō':'o','ō':'o','Ṓ':'o','ṓ':'o','Ṑ':'o','ṑ':'o','Ỏ':'o','ỏ':'o','Ȍ':'o','ȍ':'o','Ȏ':'o','ȏ':'o','Ơ':'o','ơ':'o','Ớ':'o','ớ':'o','Ờ':'o','ờ':'o','Ỡ':'o','ỡ':'o','Ở':'o','ở':'o','Ợ':'o','ợ':'o','Ọ':'o','ọ':'o','Ộ':'o','ộ':'o','Ɵ':'o','ɵ':'o','Ṕ':'p','ṕ':'p','Ṗ':'p','ṗ':'p','Ᵽ':'p','Ƥ':'p','ƥ':'p','P':'p','̃':'p','p':'p','̃':'p','ʠ':'q','Ɋ':'q','ɋ':'q','Ŕ':'r','ŕ':'r','Ř':'r','ř':'r','Ṙ':'r','ṙ':'r','Ŗ':'r','ŗ':'r','Ȑ':'r','ȑ':'r','Ȓ':'r','ȓ':'r','Ṛ':'r','ṛ':'r','Ṝ':'r','ṝ':'r','Ṟ':'r','ṟ':'r','Ɍ':'r','ɍ':'r','ᵲ':'r','ɼ':'r','Ɽ':'r','ɽ':'r','ɾ':'r','ᵳ':'r','ß':'s','Ś':'s','ś':'s','Ṥ':'s','ṥ':'s','Ŝ':'s','ŝ':'s','Š':'s','š':'s','Ṧ':'s','ṧ':'s','Ṡ':'s','ṡ':'s','ẛ':'s','Ş':'s','ş':'s','Ṣ':'s','ṣ':'s','Ṩ':'s','ṩ':'s','Ș':'s','ș':'s','ʂ':'s','S':'s','̩':'s','s':'s','̩':'s','Þ':'t','þ':'t','Ť':'t','ť':'t','T':'t','̈':'t','ẗ':'t','Ṫ':'t','ṫ':'t','Ţ':'t','ţ':'t','Ṭ':'t','ṭ':'t','Ț':'t','ț':'t','Ṱ':'t','ṱ':'t','Ṯ':'t','ṯ':'t','Ŧ':'t','ŧ':'t','Ⱦ':'t','ⱦ':'t','ᵵ':'t','ƫ':'t','Ƭ':'t','ƭ':'t','Ʈ':'t','ʈ':'t','ȶ':'t','Ú':'u','ú':'u','Ù':'u','ù':'u','Ŭ':'u','ŭ':'u','Û':'u','û':'u','Ǔ':'u','ǔ':'u','Ů':'u','ů':'u','Ü':'u','ü':'u','Ǘ':'u','ǘ':'u','Ǜ':'u','ǜ':'u','Ǚ':'u','ǚ':'u','Ǖ':'u','ǖ':'u','Ű':'u','ű':'u','Ũ':'u','ũ':'u','Ṹ':'u','ṹ':'u','Ų':'u','ų':'u','Ū':'u','ū':'u','Ṻ':'u','ṻ':'u','Ủ':'u','ủ':'u','Ȕ':'u','ȕ':'u','Ȗ':'u','ȗ':'u','Ư':'u','ư':'u','Ứ':'u','ứ':'u','Ừ':'u','ừ':'u','Ữ':'u','ữ':'u','Ử':'u','ử':'u','Ự':'u','ự':'u','Ụ':'u','ụ':'u','Ṳ':'u','ṳ':'u','Ṷ':'u','ṷ':'u','Ṵ':'u','ṵ':'u','Ʉ':'u','ʉ':'u','Ṽ':'v','ṽ':'v','Ṿ':'v','ṿ':'v','Ʋ':'v','ʋ':'v','Ẃ':'w','ẃ':'w','Ẁ':'w','ẁ':'w','Ŵ':'w','ŵ':'w','W':'w','̊':'w','ẘ':'w','Ẅ':'w','ẅ':'w','Ẇ':'w','ẇ':'w','Ẉ':'w','ẉ':'w','Ẍ':'x','ẍ':'x','Ẋ':'x','ẋ':'x','Ý':'y','ý':'y','Ỳ':'y','ỳ':'y','Ŷ':'y','ŷ':'y','Y':'y','̊':'y','ẙ':'y','Ÿ':'y','ÿ':'y','Ỹ':'y','ỹ':'y','Ẏ':'y','ẏ':'y','Ȳ':'y','ȳ':'y','Ỷ':'y','ỷ':'y','Ỵ':'y','ỵ':'y','ʏ':'y','Ɏ':'y','ɏ':'y','Ƴ':'y','ƴ':'y','Ź':'z','ź':'z','Ẑ':'z','ẑ':'z','Ž':'z','ž':'z','Ż':'z','ż':'z','Ẓ':'z','ẓ':'z','Ẕ':'z','ẕ':'z','Ƶ':'z','ƶ':'z','Ȥ':'z','ȥ':'z','ʐ':'z','ʑ':'z','Ⱬ':'z','ⱬ':'z','Ǯ':'z','ǯ':'z','ƺ':'z','２':'2','６':'6','Ｂ':'B','Ｆ':'F','Ｊ':'J','Ｎ':'N','Ｒ':'R','Ｖ':'V','Ｚ':'Z','ｂ':'b','ｆ':'f','ｊ':'j','ｎ':'n','ｒ':'r','ｖ':'v','ｚ':'z','１':'1','５':'5','９':'9','Ａ':'A','Ｅ':'E','Ｉ':'I','Ｍ':'M','Ｑ':'Q','Ｕ':'U','Ｙ':'Y','ａ':'a','ｅ':'e','ｉ':'i','ｍ':'m','ｑ':'q','ｕ':'u','ｙ':'y','０':'0','４':'4','８':'8','Ｄ':'D','Ｈ':'H','Ｌ':'L','Ｐ':'P','Ｔ':'T','Ｘ':'X','ｄ':'d','ｈ':'h','ｌ':'l','ｐ':'p','ｔ':'t','ｘ':'x','３':'3','７':'7','Ｃ':'C','Ｇ':'G','Ｋ':'K','Ｏ':'O','Ｓ':'S','Ｗ':'W','ｃ':'c','ｇ':'g','ｋ':'k','ｏ':'o','ｓ':'s','ｗ':'w'
};

function accent_fold (s) {
    if (!s) { return ''; }

    var ret = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        ret += accent_map[s.charAt(i)] || s.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
};

$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch = function (data) {
    return accent_fold(data);
};
```

I modified your question's original code to use an [accent-folding function (available on Github)](https://github.com/aristus/accent-folding/blob/master/accent-fold.js). You might also be interested in [the original article from "A List Apart"](http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete).

Answer (score 1):

For future readers,

using accent-neutralise only solves part of the problem of searching in a case-insensitive way.  The plugin only replaces some accented chars to non-accented chars inside the table. You will also need to remove accents from your search textbox input.

Another problem I had is that the plugin only replaces lowercase letters, so I went ahead and added some extra mapping for the most common accented letters in french, based on this other great solution:
[Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings)

accent-neutralise-french.js

```
function accents_supr(data){
return !data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
        data
            .replace(/\n/g, ' ')
            .replace(/[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g, 'a')
            .replace(/[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g, 'e')
            .replace(/[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g, 'i')
            .replace(/[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]/g, 'o')
            .replace(/[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g, 'u')
            .replace(/[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]/g, 'A')
            .replace(/[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]/g, 'E')
            .replace(/[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]/g, 'I')
            .replace(/[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]/g, 'O')
            .replace(/[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]/g, 'U')
            .replace(/ç/g, 'c')
            .replace(/Ç/g, 'C') :
        data;
};

jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search['string'] = function(data) {
    return accents_supr(data);
};
```

In your page with a dataTable :

```
 // Remove accented character from search input as well
    $('#dt_basic_filter input[type=search]').keyup( function () {
        var table = $('#dt_basic').DataTable(); 
        table.search(
            jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string(this.value)
        ).draw();
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional feedback on column filtering : the comments above will only work if the column to filter is of type "string" (the DataTables column type defined [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type)).

If the column contains HTML tags, the DataTables lib will automagically tag it as "html" type, and it will trigger the associated search callback on that type. Therefore for the filtering to apply properly, the callback needs to be registered on the "html" type :

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search['html'] = function(data) {
  return unaccent(data);
};
```

where unaccent is a function that removes accents / diacritics / strange characters from the input string.

Answer (score 1):

My question is the same about searching without accent but finding answers with accent like search with cafe and display results with café.

I don't use a table but div and I don't have the clue to adapt the solutions to my site.

Here is my code for searching:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV div").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```