# datatables - Individual column searching with accent neutralise

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to search in columns with accent neutralise plugin, but it didnt work at all. It transform searched text to accentless, but it doesnt match the results. I want to search **Kollar** and with result **Kollár**.

Example:

1. Searched name **Kollar** with no result, but in table is **Kollár** multiple times.
2. Searched name **Kollár** with no result...

Here is the code:

```
var table = jQuery('#example').DataTable();
jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function ( data ) {
    return ! data ?
        '' :
       typeof data === 'string' ?
              data
                        .replace( /έ/g, 'ε')
                        .replace( /ύ/g, 'υ')
                        .replace( /ό/g, 'ο')
                        .replace( /ώ/g, 'ω')
                        .replace( /ά/g, 'α')
                        .replace( /ί/g, 'ι')
                        .replace( /ή/g, 'η')
                        .replace( /\n/g, ' ' )
                        .replace( /á/g, 'a' )
                        .replace( /é/g, 'e' )
                        .replace( /í/g, 'i' )
                        .replace( /ó/g, 'o' )
                        .replace( /ú/g, 'u' )
                        .replace( /ê/g, 'e' )
                        .replace( /î/g, 'i' )
                        .replace( /ô/g, 'o' )
                        .replace( /è/g, 'e' )
                        .replace( /ï/g, 'i' )
                        .replace( /ü/g, 'u' )
                        .replace( /ã/g, 'a' )
                        .replace( /õ/g, 'o' )
                        .replace( /ç/g, 'c' )
                        .replace( /ì/g, 'i' ) :
                    data;
        };

    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
            jQuery( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                table
                    .column( colIdx )
                    .search(
                        jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string( this.value )
                    )
                    .draw();
            });
        });
```

EDIT: Its not a duplicate of [jQuery DataTables - Accent-Insensitive Alphabetization and Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833584/jquery-datatables-accent-insensitive-alphabetization-and-searching) becouse I need it to column searching not for global search. Ive already read it and it doesnt works for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables - Accent-Insensitive Alphabetization and Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833584/jquery-datatables-accent-insensitive-alphabetization-and-searching)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the table. It contains empty (only white space) cells and in this case whole table didnt filter with accent neutralise function. So I change white space to `&nbsp;` and it works like a charm :). It cost me lot of time to find it out :).